# Removing users from roles

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-membership

I have a massive list of users that need to be removed from certain roles in my .net membership database.

Rather than use the front end to do this, which would take an age, I wondered if it would be safe to just remove the records from the aspnet_UsersInRoles table in SQL directly in the database?

```
DELETE FROM [webMembership].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles]
 WHERE [UserId] IN (SELECT [UserId]
                      FROM [webMembership].[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles]
                     WHERE [RoleId] IN (SELECT [RoleId]
                                          FROM [webMembership].[dbo].[aspnet_Roles]
                                         WHERE [RoleName] LIKE 'WAR%')
                       AND [UserId] IN (SELECT [UserId]
                                          FROM [webMembership].[dbo].[CustomProfile]
                                         WHERE [CustomerCountry] = 'NO'))
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. You should just make a previous backup of your database.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. But actually looked at the stored procedure in the .net database for removing users from roles and it basically ends with the same query (albeit a different where clause)